# Problema con if y else al usar Firebase en Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estoy usando la base de datos de Firebase en mi proyecto. El problema es que cuando quiero guardar un X usuario con una X puntuacion, muestra carteles de todos los usuarios de la base de datos, cuando debería mostrar un solo cartel anunciando el usuario y su puntuación. Si el usuario existe lo carga igual. Además, muestra carteles de carga exitosa y a la vez de fallo que he definido. ¿En qué estoy fallando?

```
//Busca la referencia Scores, sino, la crea y busca ramas y las imprime en la consola
function buscar() {
    $("#scoreData").html("<div class='preloader-wrapper small active'><div class='spinner-layer spinner-green-only'><div class='circle-clipper left'><div class='circle'></div></div><div class='gap-patch'><div class='circle'></div></div><div class='circle-clipper right'><div class='circle'></div></div></div></div>");
    //URl de las scores
    var qn = firebase.database().ref('Scores/');
    //buscamos scores
    qn.once('value', function (scores) {
        $("#scoreData").html("");
        scores.forEach(function (score) {
            var var_score = score.val();
            var addToTable = "<tr><td>" + var_score.Usuario + "</td><td>" + var_score.Puntuación + "</td></tr>";
            $("#scoreData").append(addToTable);
            console.log(var_score);
        });
    });
}
//Guarda un Usuario con su puntuacion a la base de datos de firebase y luego levanta la lista de ramas en la referencia
function guardar() {

    var scoreData = {
        Usuario: $("#Usuario").val(),
        Puntuación: $("#Puntuación").val(),
    };
    var refer = firebase.database().ref('Scores/');

//Recuperar los datos y comparar con el input, no esta funcionando
refer.orderByChild("Usuario").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val().Usuario == scoreData.Usuario) {
        console.log("No se pudo guardar");
        //Cartel flotante
        Materialize.toast('Ya existe el usuario ' + scoreData.Usuario+ ". Intente con otro nombre.", 5000, 'rounded');
    } else {
        // Get a key for a new Post.
        var scoreKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Scores').push().key;

        // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
        var updates = {};
        updates['/Scores/' + scoreKey] = scoreData;  

        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
        buscar();
        console.log("Guardando");
        //cartel flotante para anunciar exitosa carga
        Materialize.toast('Puntuación de '+ scoreData.Puntuación + ' agregada con éxito para ' + scoreData.Usuario, 5000, 'rounded');
    }
});
}
buscar();
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                    <input id="Usuario" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="icon_prefix">Usuario</label>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                    <input id="Puntuación" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="icon_prefix">Puntuación</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="guardar()">ENVIAR</a>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field='id'>Usuario</th>
                <th data-field='name'>Puntuación</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="scoreData" style="text-align:center"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos problemas, el uso de una variable con ACENTO (Puntuación).
Y luego en la última linea generas el llamado a la función BUSCAR y lo haces después de

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el uso de acento es un problema? Investigué un poco, según entendí de http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names JavaScript si permite acentos.